# Mouseout and Mouseover events not firing properly in Chrome 39

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

Using Chrome 39 (for Mac) the following does not work

```
<div id='canvasWrapper'>
    <canvas id='main0'></canvas>
    <canvas id='main1'></canvas>
    <canvas id='main2'></canvas>
    <div id='mainToolbar'>
        <img src='magnify.png'>
        <img src='pencil.png'>
        <img src='plus.png'>
        <img src='ex.png'>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var wrap = document.getElementById('canvasWrapper');
    wrap.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
        document.getElementById('mainToolbar').style.display = 'block';
    })
    wrap.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
        document.getElementById('mainToolbar').style.display = 'none';
    })
    var imgs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'));
    imgs.forEach(function(img) {
        img.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
            var string = img.className;
            string += ' inverted';
            img.className = string;
        })
        img.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
            var string = img.className.split(' ').filter(function(classy) {
                return classy != 'inverted';
            }).join(' ');
            img.className = string;
        })
    })
</script>
```

The toolbar with the icons should reveal when the user mouses over the canvas-containing div, hide on `mouseout`. With the images, mousing over them adds a class that contains the `css filter` property to invert the colors. All this works exactly as expected in Safari 7.1 and even on FF 28. However, in chrome the events only trigger when clicking on or outside the `canvasWrapper` div. Setting the function on the `onmouseover` property of the div makes no difference compared to `addEventListener`. If this is a known bug in Chrome 35+ minutes of Googling it has not yielded results. Does anyone know why/how to fix this?

PS, not sure its relevant or not but the canvases are layers: they all are the same size and overlap exactly.

Comment: Check your `imgs` array actually contains what it should: I've never seen `[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img'));` before, try using `document.getElementsByTagName("img")`.

Comment: in this case what I wrote is more or less equivalent. Only difference as far as I know is that the nodeList returned by `querySelectorAll` is not live, it does not reflect changes to the DOM since the list was culled (`getElementsByTagName` returns a 'live' list)

Comment: I don't think inverted, as a class, does anything by default in chrome; have you set up your css correctly?

Comment: It seems to work for me fine, the behavior just seems a little glitchy: http://jsfiddle.net/theonlygusti/grrzsryt/

Comment: I figured it out, but thanks for the help +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I posted the answer here in case anyone else has this problem. It works fine in chrome *only* if you are actually viewing the page through a webserver. If you just open the file with chrome, it does not work. This is untrue with the other browsers. Not sure why this works in everything but chrome, but there you have it.

Comment: btw, should I file a bug with the chrome dev team on this?

Comment: This is a 'feature' not a bug.  There are many reports of the same issue.  Its an annoying 'feature' but there are zillions of posts around the web about it.

Comment: Thanks I'll leave it alone. Its def a violation of 'principle of least surprise' though, not sure what they gain by being the odd one out there.

Comment: @josh.chavanne in what way is this a feature? Sounds like a bug to me

Comment: @B T Thus my quotes around 'feature' - the Chrome team knows about this and it was intended.  I believe they justify it as a security 'feature'.

The OP noted that this behavior only happens when loading a file from the filesystem and not from a server.  I imagine the Chrome Dev team intends to not allow 'arbitrary' javascript to run in Chrome from the filesystem.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224215

Comment: While I don't necessarily disagree with that approach, its frustrating when they're the only ones who do it that way