# Requesting files with javascript when using file:// protocol

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a small web app that consumes data from an XML file to display. It's basically just 3 files:

```
app.html
logic.js
data.xml
```

The javascript file loads the XML data and processes it:

```
$.get('data.xml', {}, processResult);
```

I would like this little app to be able to run when launched locally with the `file://` protocol. However I am getting the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/.../data.xml' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

Basically I need a way for javascript to request another file in the same directory. Is this possible? I can make any changes to the JS or HTML files but the XML file comes from a vendor and it would be a pain to modify it each time (e.g. to wrap it in JSON or JSONP).

Comment: No you can't do that. Just use a local web server. Browsers *really* don't like web pages touching the file system.

Comment: @JaredSmith : my use case requires users to be able to load these files on their computer, so a local a web server is a no-go. As I said in another comment it's weird that I can load javascript files locally with `<script src="logic.js"></script>`. Obviously I understand that you don't want an http site to poke around on the file system but that is not really the case here, the browser is already opening local files.

Comment: "my use case requires users to be able to load these files on their computer" then you're going to have to use something other than a webpage. "Obviously I understand that you don't want an http site to poke around on the file system" yes, exactly, so you aren't going to be able to use it to poke around on the file system. In addition to the sandboxing issues you're going to find that a lot of stuff (e.g. [mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680329/mouseout-and-mouseover-events-not-firing-properly-in-chrome-39)) won't work correctly when executing with the `file://` protocol.

Comment: @JaredSmith I suppose in a perfect world I would have the time to port the app to Electron or something. But this is an internal business app and I have to be pragmatic. I have decided to just wrap the XML as a javascript string, e.g. `var xml = '<?xml>...';` and then load it via `<script src="data.xml.js"></script>`. It's dumb but it works over `file://`.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to hack it, no shame. Seriously though watch out for the mouse event thing, I see that pop up as a question here pretty regularly.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern browsers have a security policy where you're not allowed to do certain things in javascript via `file://`

If you want to run your app locally you can write a simple http server in node, go, or whatever or just install one like https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Then you can access it via `http://localhost:`

Comment: Just seems weird that I can load javascript files via `file://` using `<script src="logic.js"></script>` but I can't get other resources that way.

Comment: I think it's to prevent js code from remote websites from accessing a user's file system via `file://`. I'm guessing you can't access files with javascript but you can load js or other files because those file names are explicitly stated in the html.