# Why can I import a script file from a local directory but I can't when the type is a module?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, local, es6-modules, script-tag

Let's say you create a project folder named 'project' in your desktop and inside of it a simple index.html file.
Now, you want to create a script and so to not polute your index.html, you code your script inside a script.js file and then import it in your index.html using `<script src="script.js"></script>`.

This works flawlessly! However, if you just so wish to make it an ES6 module by using `type="module"`, you'll face a CORS policy block error and the script will not load.

Why does this happen? Is there any way to use ES6 modules in local files without coding directly in a script tag within the html file? Is this ever going to be supported?

Using a bundler/compiler is out of question in this scenario as it is inteded to be as simple as possible, but using ES6.

Comment: "you'll face a CORS policy block error and the script will not load" works fine on my machine, what web server are you using?

Comment: @JaredSmith No web server, running using ```file://```

Comment: Yeah, that's your problem then. Use an actually web server. All kinds of stuff ([like mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680329/mouseout-and-mouseover-events-not-firing-properly-in-chrome-39)) will fail to work properly if you're opening it using a file url. You can use `serve` [from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve/v/14.0.1), or if you're on Mac or Linux you almost certainly have Python installed by default and Python has a built in simple webserver that can be invoked directly from the command line (without having to write any Python code).

Comment: Is there a workaround for this specific problem, though? The idea is to build a simple utility tool that serves an specfic purpose, pack it as ZIP and share internally for it to be used by non-technical team members, so it has be as simple as possible. To be honest, giving the instruction "extract the ZIP file and launch index.html" is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: No there is no workaround. You say it works flawlessly but that's only because you haven't gotten far enough yet to hit stuff that won't work this way. Just use something else. Set up an internal server and tell them to go to the webpage instead of distributing as a zip. If that's not an option maybe make an electron app. Or use pygtk. Or something. But this is waaay outside of the usecase for a *web*page, and you are going to find that lots of things just don't work.

Comment: @JaredSmith also possible to just have a simple bundle process that converts the project to be a module-less web page. Then users won't need to do anything extra once they are shipped an HTML file to click on.

Comment: @VLAZ...assuming all the e.g. event handlers work properly (per my link in an earlier comment). Even if everything works right now there's no guarantee that it will stay that way as the requirements change over time. I still maintain there's a reason people don't usually do that and the OP is in for some soul-sucking tech debt if they don't change course. But yes, you could do that with a simple script that inlines the JS in the HTML document.

Comment: @VLAZ That might solve the module loading problem, but you still wouldn't be able to access any HTTPS-only Web APIs

Comment: There is no reason to worry about this though, as this is not a project per see, but rather a simple utility tool not meant to scale and just be a handy tool to test some stuff. Since there's no way, there's no way. I'll try to bundle together with an web server, maybe a Spring Boot artifact with static files would do. Thank you all, I'm closing the question.